# How do I stop all the Microsoft Logging scope information?

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I have a C# Blazor .Net Core 5 Server side app, I'm using the baked-in Microsoft Logging ILogger logging mechanism. My problem is not its verbosity, I know how to control that, my problem is how much text it outputs into the log. For example:

```
09:48:16 info: <My ServiceClass>[0] => SpanId:d09ee3ddfeb3ea42, TraceId:499476de9917a74aab60adff72a7da86, ParentId:0000000000000000 => ConnectionId:0HMAIEL3FMOVV => RequestPath:/ RequestId:0HMAIEL3FMOVV:00000002 => /_Host => <My Scope>
```

The bits in <> are redactions

This makes the logs really hard to read in the console, where it's all line wrapped. The SpanId, TraceId, ParentID, ConnectionID, RequestPath/RequestID and the word /_Host are always the same value per instance and totally redundant information. Can I remove them from the logging scope?